# .NET HttpClient doesn't reuse tcp connections for parallel requests

Tags: .net

I have the following nodejs server. It serves only json on HTTP and records whenever a new tcp connection is established:

```
var http = require('http');

var response = [{"name":"Alice"},{"name":"Bob"}];
var count=0;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
}).on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('new TCP stream is established ' + count)
  count++;
  socket.setTimeout(5000);
}).listen(5000);
```

I query this server with the following C# program that starts 10 http requests and doesn't wait for their response

```
//to check connection reuse across processes
Console.WriteLine("ProcessID " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mypc.domain.com:5000");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var result = client.GetAsync("/"); // or client.GetAsync("/").Result
    Console.Writeline("requested " + i);
}
```

When I run it I see the following output:

new TCP stream is established 0
.
.
new TCP stream is established 9

It created 10 tcp connections.

<s>Now when I run the C# program in quick succession (under the 5 second timeout set on the server). I don't see any new TCP connections being created. The 10 new requests reuse the TCP connections from the previous run.</s>

Is there a way to have HttpClient only create and reuse one TCP connection for parallel requests?
Is it possible to make parallel requests over the same TCP connection at all?

Comment: I am very shocked it reused connections at all. Are you sure you don't just loose the output of the 2nd test? If you put a `console.log` in the `createServer` how many responses do you process, 10, or 20?

Comment: you're right the program exits before any requests can be made. I was trying this from LinqPad which apparently keeps the process running.  
But if I made the requests sequentially, I could run the second run from a .exe and still see only one tcp connection being created (from the first run)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you want to reuse one connection for everything, especially with the "fire-and-forget" style of your client code. GetAsync is returning a Task object, whose Result property will be filled in when the Task completes. If you need the result before moving on, use a non-async pattern.

Comment: @Spivonious The "fire and forget" style is for demonstration purposes.   Also, me needing the result has nothing to do with async vs non-async. I could need the results of these 10 requests and still make them in parallel. I don't see any problems there.

Comment: "TCP connection for parallel requests?
Is it possible to make parallel requests over the same TCP connection at all?" yes but the other end must be designed to handle it. Also they won't be truely parallel, it will just be a bunch of messages queued up in a queue that get processed in sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're starting requests extremely quickly they all require a new connection. There should not be any reuse (not guaranteed but likely).

> Now when I run the C# program in quick succession

There is no connection reuse across processes. There is no reuse here. However you thought you found that to be true - it's not. I'm not familiar with node.

> Is there a way to have HttpClient only create and reuse one TCP connection for parallel requests?

TCP connections can only run multiple HTTP requests in parallel through pipelining which is not a sure way to optimize. I think you can turn on HTTP pipelining with .NET.

> Is it possible to make parallel requests over the same TCP connection at all?

Yes, by pipelining.

I don't think pipelining should necessarily be your goal since it also serializes responses.

You probably should rely on HTTP keep alive which, I think, is on by default. There is no harm in 10 TCP connections existing. If you change your program a bit you will see 100% reuse:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var result = client.GetAsync("/").Result; //Wait here
    Console.Writeline("requested " + i);
}
```

Or:

```
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var result = client.GetAsync("/"); //NO waiting here
        Console.Writeline("requested " + i);
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //wait/hope for requests to finish
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly, there is connection reuse across processes. I tried the sequential program with `Result`. The node server only created one tcp connection across multiple runs of the exe.  
  
Thank you for your comment about pipelining. I will look into that or just consider making things serial.

Comment: I bet you money there is no reuse. There is no mechanism to achieve that in .NET or in Windows. Your measurement is wrong, or you are not starting new requests in new processes. You'll eventually discover which one of these it is.

Comment: Ah it looks like it was Fiddler that was causing the connection reuse. Closing it creates a new one for each run. :)

Comment: There you go :) Strictly speaking neither of my two possibilities is matched by this particular failure mode.

Comment: You still would have won the bet I guess